# can i create array of layers in core animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to create multiple layers for multiple images of an array. i want to create each layer for each object of an array. the array contains 10 objects with different image and i want to draw at different positions.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create explicit layers by allocating a [CALayer alloc]init], then setBounds: and setPosition: on it. You can draw onto these layers and use something like Core Animation to animate them if you wish.

The CALayer is an object, so you can use an array container (or other containers, sets, dictionaries) to hold them.